# Using WinGHCi to implement first Haskell program

Tags: haskell

This is not my code :

```
import Data.Monoid (Endo (..), appEndo)
import Data.Foldable (foldMap)

-- | chainEndos chain a list of endomorphisms to create a new one
-- Point-free version is feasible and redable.
-- Level: Easy
--
-- Examples:
--
-- >>> chainEndos [(+1),(*3)] 2
-- 7
-- >>> chainEndos [('h':),('e':)] "llo"
-- "hello"
--
-- >>> chainEndos [] (12 :: Int)
-- 12
--
chainEndos :: [a->a] -> a -> a
chainEndos = appEndo . foldMap Endo

chainEndos' :: [a->a] -> a -> a
chainEndos' = foldr (.) id

main = print $ chainEndos [('h':),('e':)] "llo"
```

I would like to run this in the Haskell IDE : http://www.haskell.org/platform/

But WinGhci offers just a repl like structure ? How can I load this as haskell file and run it ?

Comment: The Haskell Platform isn't an IDE.  It provides GHC, a compiler, and GHCi, an interactive REPL, along with a set of libraries.  Are you wanting to compile this code into an executable?  Just do `ghc --make myFile.hs`.  If you want to load it into GHCi interactively, run `ghci`, then type `:l path/to/myFile.hs`.

Comment: @bheklilr WinGhci is included in the Haskell Platform for Windows, and has a graphical interface for loading files and the like (see Heather's answer). It's not a full IDE though. Of course, being a wrapper over ghci, your :l command will also work in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save it to file, then

`File -> Load`

that's all, after it you can call `main`